# Python py2exe dll load fail mixer module not available

Tags: python, module, pygame, exe, py2exe

I tried to make an exe from my programm in python using py2exe. The problem is, that when I try to run the exe, it gives me an error:

```
C:\Users\Eduard\Desktop\testordner>test.exe
test.exe:7: RuntimeWarning: use mixer: DLL load failed: Das
angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
(ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
mixer.init()
File "pygame\__init__.pyc", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: mixer module not available
(ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
```

Here is my setupfile too:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import Tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle
from pygame import mixer
import random
import py2exe

setup(console=[{"script":"test.py"}],options={"py2exe":{"includes":["pygame"]}})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to add 'pygame' in the 'packages' option instead of 'includes'.

If above is not enough I would do some googling for 'pygame and py2exe'